# Multiply lists: element-wise but matrix-like in the last 2 levels

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning

How can I do the following computation more efficiently? We have nested lists and want to multiply element-wise, where the 'element' is the deepest 2 levels treated like normal matrix multiplication. And then we `Total` all but the last 2 levels. In reality I need to deal with larger size (like `d1=300` but still small `d2`) lists many many times. Probably the following is not the optimal way to program it.

```
d1 = 10; d2 = 2;
mat1 = RandomComplex[1 + I, {d1, d1, d2, d2}];
mat2 = RandomComplex[1 + I, {d1, d1, d2, d2}];
mat3 = ConjugateTranspose[mat1];
data = Table[mat1[[i, j]] . mat2[[i, j]] . mat3[[i, j]], {i, d1}, {j, d1}];
Total[data, 2];
```

Comment: The code you provided executes practically instantaneously and it is reasonably readable. What is the problem with it?

Comment: I also like your method. You can also do `Apply[Dot, Transpose[{mat1, mat2, mat3}, {3, 1, 2}], {2}]` to get `data` but  it is easier to see what is being done using your approach.

Comment: @kglr Thanks, this is faster than my `Table`. Nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the numbers are machine floats (complex ones), this will be fast:

```
data3 = Compile[
    {{m1, _Complex, 2}, {m2, _Complex, 2}, {m3, _Complex, 2}},
    m1 . m2 . m3,
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
    Parallelization -> True][mat1, mat2, mat3];
```

(If `d1` is changed to `d1 =300`, then the OP's `Table[]` runs in `0.34` sec. and the above in `0.012` sec.)

Comment: Thank you. Can I include the `Total[..., 2]` operation into this compiled function?

Comment: @xiaohuamao Apparently not: the `Total[a, 2]` form is not compilable. However, you can put it outside: `Total[Compile[ ...][mat1, mat2, mat3], 2]`.  `Total` is quite efficient on packed arrays (which is what `Compile` returns), and putting it inside `Compile` doesn't usually speed it up much.  In this case adding it on the outside adds very little time for `d1 = 300`.